# Make View visible outside TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, constraints

Is it possible to have a `view` inside a `tableViewCell` and make it visible even outside the `tableView-frame`?

I would need this for an animation. I tried setting `clipsToBounde = false` but that didn't solve the issue. The `view` is still cut outside the `tableViewFrame`.

My `view` inside `tableViewCell`:

```
 func setupLoadingAnimation(){

    successAnimation.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    successAnimation.clipsToBounds = false
    self.contentView.addSubview(successAnimation)

    successAnimation.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: -60).isActive = true
    successAnimation.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    successAnimation.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true
    successAnimation.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 160).isActive = true

    successAnimation.isHidden = true
    successAnimation.loopMode = .playOnce
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to make sure all views in the hierarchy have their clipping set to `false`. Start with the superview of `successAnimation` and go up through the hierarchy, this will include the cell's `contentView` and the table view itself.

Another thing you'll have to look for is that views that are added to the hierarchy later will show on top of others if they are at the same level, and since a table view manages its cells it's hard to know which cells are going to overlap your animation.

To fix this you could call `bringSubviewToFront()` on your table view and pass the cell, I would do this right before executing the success animation.

Another alternative would be to place the table and success views in a shared parent, that way you only have to make sure that the success view is above the table view once, when you add the views.

Comment: That was it thanks :) Actually I only had to set the clipping to `false` in the `tableView`. That's the only one needed.